# Why does my z-index does not work ? I want my side bar to apper on top of everything .i have set z-index to 10000; but still cards overlap it

Tags: css, z-index, positioning, sidebar, overlapping

I want my sidebar to appear on top of everything .i have set z-index to 10000, but still, cards overlap it
the css of the sidebar and founder card is

```css
.sidemenu{
      position: fixed;
     top: 0px;
     width: 240px;
     margin-left: -250px;
     overflow: hidden;
     height: 100vh;
     background: black;
     opacity: 1; 
      z-index: 100000000000000;
     transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
} 
    .founders {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        color: white;    
}
```

Comment: can you provide working code..? there is no output.

Comment: Provide your HTML code to solve

Comment: Thank you so much for helping

here's the link for the page

[link](https://codepen.io/poojavpatel71/project/editor/XzxJWR)

Answer (score 0):

Might be this will help

```
 .sidemenu {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     margin-left: 100vw;
     overflow: hidden;
     height: 100vh;
     background: black;
     opacity: 1;
     z-index: 100000000000000;
     transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 }

 .founders {
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     flex-direction: column;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     color: white;
 }
<div class="sidemenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="founders">
    <div class="item">
        this is founder
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding.

here's the link to the page [codepen link](https://codepen.io/poojavpatel71/project/editor/XzxJWR)

can u please check it out